# Convert HTML to .eps format for illustrator

Tags: html, printing, submit, adobe-illustrator, eps

I have a letterhead of a company made in HTML, Where the user fills in his Company Details and rest of the information. When the user clicks on the SUMBMIT button that particular form should convert it to .eps format and then PRINT.

Does any one have any clue of how its done.

Comment: @MotaBOS can you check this link. I have downloaded the commandline of this software I thought I could use this. Confused on how to use it as I'm running the command line, it appears for 1 sec and disappears. http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201109/how-to-convert-a-document-of-html-to-eps-format-3121.html

Comment: Its little late on my side, signing off, will check it tomorrow. ok buddy ?

Comment: @MotaBOS Its alright I appreciate your time to reply and provide solution. Thanks.

Comment: Browsers will send PostScript (eps= Encapsulated PostScript, its just a file format) to the printer, and the printed page will look great. You don't need anything special, `print()` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how to convert html form to .eps format for illustrator. But since you also mentioned that you want to print that form to printer you can do something like this -

1. When user clicks on print button call a js function `createHTML()` which reads all the form data and create an html. for eg.

   `var html = "<h1>"+$('#nameField').val()+"</h1>" +`
                         `"<p>"+$('#msgField').val()+"</p>";`
2. Now create a new window in js as below -

   `win = window.open(", ", 'popup', 'toolbar = no, status = no');`
   `win.document.write("" + html + "");`
3. Then call `win.print()`

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/WrTwW/