# how to convert HTML file to a image file

Tags: html, forms, submit, eps

I have a letterhead made using HTML, I want to convert it to an image how can it be done . And I want to use it my site,i.e when the user clicks on the SUBMIT button it should convert it in the background....

Comment: Do you want to save that image or immediately want to print it ?

Comment: @MotaBOS I didn't want to save now Print it, Because I wanted to convert that image to .eps file for illustrator...

Comment: if you want to just print it. Check my answer on [Convert HTML to .eps format for illustrator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241222/convert-html-to-eps-format-for-illustrator/11242412#11242412). I have no idea how to save it in `.eps` format but I guess when you get the print wizard there you get the option print to file, which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBScript to convert your HTML page into image

```
Dim snap

'Create the Html Snapshot Object
Set snap = CreateObject("HTMLSNAP2.HtmlSnap.1")

'Begin to capture the web page
snap.SnapUrl "http://www.google.com/", "google.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, then you could look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963900/php-library-for-converting-html-to-image

There are several solutions to the problem there.

You can have your script send the HTML to the server when the user clicks 'submit', and then return the result. Most of the solutions are quite fast I should have thought, depending on the complexity of the HTML to be converted....

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript library called html2canvas
this library can convert a specific object in html (it might be block, table, etc) into a image with .png extension.

https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/